# Running JPOS Client and Server Simulator on the same machine throws error

Tags: jpos

I am following the instructions from here : http://jpos.org/blog/2013/07/setting-up-the-client-simulator/ to set up the client and server simulator. I am able to start one of them on my machine. If i start the server after the client is run, it throws this error :

"An instance of Q2 is already running. Shutting this instance"

I know its kind of self explanatory. But was wondering if there is a way to run both server and client simulators on the same machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `src/dist/deploy` directory and remove the file 01_multi_instance_prevention.xml`. That descriptor wasn't present in jPOS by the time the blog post was written and was installed when you called`installResources` as it's now part of the jPOS jar. We'll consider making that file optional.